# Can't run perl scripts from server in EPIC (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, perl, server, epic

I'm trying to edit Perl scripts on a company server (test server so far) with Eclipse using the EPIC plugin. I managed to get so far as to be able to load folders with scripts, and open the scripts properly, but any time I try to run them, I get the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching --FileName--".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Image:

[image: Perl Error - javaLangNullPointException]

I have no idea what could be wrong, as Padre (Perl IDE) runs these files properly. I am updating my Perl to the latest version as I write this, but I don't think that the difference between `5.14` and `5.22` would be the problem.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on the Launch Configuration of Eclipse.
http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch06s02.php